# Sair de vários loops sem usar goto

Tags: c, c++

Opa! O título diz tudo! Alguém sabe uma maneira interessante de sair de mais de um loop sem usar goto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em C é possível ter uma variável de controle que seja parte da expressão do `for` - você seta ela no loop mais interno, e isso deixa falsa as expressões dos loops mais externos. Só que o código depois do fim do loop mais interno,  mas dentro dos loops externos será executado uma última vez, ao contrário do que aconteceria com um `goto` ou uma exceção.

```
int finished = 0;
for (int i=0; !finished && i < 640; i++)
  for (int j=0; !finished && j < 480; j++)
     for (int k=0; !finished && k < 4; k++) {
        ...
        if (condition) {
            ...
            finished = 1;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Acho que essa solução é a mais elegante. A execução "extra" a que se referes pode ser evitada, se desejado, adicionando-se um `break` ou `continue`.

Comment: Essa ficou boa mesmo.

Answer (score 7):

Interessante não.

É possível usar um [*long jump*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp) em C ou [lançar uma exceção](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/throw) em em C++, mas são opções muito piores que `goto`.

Em alguns casos um simples `return` em uma função pode resolver, assim você coloca o código estrategicamente para aproveitar isso.

Você pode fazer o laço ser encerrado com a criação de variável que controle isso, é chamada de *flag*, mas complica muito o código. Chega ser ridículo como o código fica e como é complicado analisar e depurar algo assim. Fica muito pior só para atender uma demanda artificial boba. As pessoas precisam entender que não é para usar esse comando para melhorar o código, quando fica pior sem ele então é para usar. Veja na resposta acima como fica ruim. Com `goto` fica melhor:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 640; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 480; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            ...
            if (condition) {
                ...
                goto fim;
            }
        }
    }
}
:fim
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/ControlFlux/Goto.c).

Pode parecer maior, mas é só porque na outra resposta o código está incompleto. Experimenta depurar um e outro.

Então, se não puder criar uma situação que o laço se encerre naturalmente (sempre dá, mas tem caso que fica confuso demais e pode ser melhor fazer artificialmente mesmo) o melhor é usar o `goto`.

Comment: Deixa quieto... Vou usar goto mesmo...